# Can we convert PEM file into jks file using karate

Tags: karate

I need to convert the PEM file into jks file. Can we do this using karate?

In the below code I am passing jks file manually after converting from PEM file

```
* configure ssl = { trustStore: 'classpath:ic/feature/SSL2WAY/trustStoreAnu.jks', trustStorePassword: 'manage', trustStoreType: 'jks',keyStore: 'classpath:ic/feature/SSL2WAY/keyStoreAnu.jks', keyStorePassword: 'manage', keyStoreType: 'jks',trustAll: 'true',algorithm: 'TLS' };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Karate is not a tool to manage certificates. You need to convert only once and save it anyway, I don't understand the issue here.